# A Type (Class) As Placeholder? (Avoiding Copy/Paste)

Tags: c#, class, generics, types

I have this Code:

```
 OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
 myOracleConnection.Open();
 OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = 
      SchemaDifferenceFinder.Model.SQLStatements.MissingTables.DropTable;
 command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 myOracleConnection.Close();
```

On Line **4** you find "**MissingTables**". Thats a **Class**.

This *whole* Code will repeat 7 times, everything is the same, except that this Class changes, by example: "**MissingColumns**". But I don't want to copy/paste the whole code, only to replace *this* trifle.

What could I do? Something with generics? I could also pass parameters if needed etc. Am grateful for every solution!

Comment: What does it change to? Maybe you can post what a second repetition would look like (Two snippets)

Comment: Instead of MissingTables, MissingColumns, thats all

Comment: I did not see you were just assigning it to a string! `command.CommandText` both the answers provided will work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private static void ExecuteSQL(string SQL)
{
  OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
  myOracleConnection.Open();
  OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = SQL;
  command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myOracleConnection.Close(); 
}
```

Which can then be called the following way:

```
Helper.ExecuteSQL(SchemaDifferenceFinder.Model.SQLStatements.MissingTables.DropTable);
```

Comment: The OWASP top vulnerability in 2010 was SQL injection, is this method vulnerable to it?

Comment: @StuperUser - It may be. Depends on the passed in command and how it was built. It looks like a string resource that can't be changed so should be safe in this instance.

Comment: @StuperUser I all depends on where your SQL come from, if it's from the URL then yes. If it's hardcoded in your app then no.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need generics - just a wrapper method that takes the command text as parameter.

```
private void ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, string connString)
{
    using(OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
        myOracleConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note the use of the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure proper disposal.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put the code into a method with a string parameter for the command text? Something like this?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the provided CommandText against the Oracle database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The command to execute</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if an empty or null commandText is provided</exception>
    private void ExecuteOracleTextCommand(string commandText)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commandText)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("commandText", "Please provide a valid command");
        }
        //other commandText validation here...

        OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        myOracleConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myOracleConnection.Close();
    }
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
ExecuteOracleTextCommand(SchemaDifferenceFinder.Model.SQLStatements.MissingTables.DropTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer in case you want to have more control on the command from the caller:

```
private delegate void CommandAction(OracleCommand command);
private static void ExecuteNonQuery(CommandAction action)
{
  OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
  myOracleConnection.Open();

  OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
  action(command);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myOracleConnection.Close(); 
}
```

Which can then be called the following way:

```
Helper.ExecuteNonQuery(command =>
{
  command.CommandText = SchemaDifferenceFinder.Model.SQLStatements.MissingTables.DropTable;
  command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
});
```